# Symlinks not working when created

Tags: symbolic-link, fedora-14

It is a terrible title, but I don't know how else to describe it (this is probably something very simple).  I'm creating a symlink to a sub-directory one directory up:

```
ln -s ../src/django-countries
```

This executes successfully, but when I enter the symlink its contents are empty, which not the case at all.  When I do an "ll" the link is there and not blinking red (which would indicate that the link is broken).  The folders are there, and the permissions seem to be all correct at the location of the symlinked folder.

Any suggestions would be totally appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `readlink -f` to verify that the symlink actually points to where you think it's pointing.

Comment: it is in fact pointing to the right place. The was no actual content in the folder, despite being told otherwise by another developer who was working from the same git repository.  Sry to waste your time.